# Android :: apps to automatically record all phone and WhatsApp call

Tags: android, mobile, audio-recording, phone, voice-recording

I use Android and I would like to record all phone and WhatsApp call.

The process should be automatic and ideally I would like the record to be automatically deleted after 1 month.

**EDIT:** I own a OnePlus 8T so I should be the superuser of it.

Comment: What Android version is running on the phone? Is the phone rooted?

Comment: I edited my reply @Robert

Comment: OnePlus 8T so Android is 11 or 12. If your phone is running stock OS then you don't have root permissions. Only if you unlock bootloader and install e.g. Magisk you have root access. Phone recording on unrooted Android 11/12 devices is very restricted, may be even not possible.

Answer (score 1):

Boldbeast for phone conversations works perfectly on certain unrooted [phones](https://android.gadgethacks.com/how-to/boldbeast-lets-you-record-calls-any-android-phone-with-without-root-0187782/).

Comment: hi @paulj and thank you. Unfortunately Boldbeast looks deprecated

Answer (score 0):

In the end [Call Recorder - Cube ACR](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.catalinagroup.callrecorder) looks like is the only one but is not free.

Other alternatives are [Call Recorder](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.cryok.larva) but doesn't records apps and [VoIP Recorder & Screen Recorder](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.boldbeast.voiprecorder)